# Dart editor can't retrieve dependencies with Pub

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I am trying to retrieve the needed dependencies for my newest project that I was going to try out Angular Dart with but every time I try to retrieve the dependencies like angular and web components packages, I get and error. The message in the editor console is: 
"Pub get failed, [69] Resolving dependencies...
Connection closed before full header was received

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **"

I did run it again a few times to see if that would fix it and it did not, it only made the same message again.

I am using dart sdk version 1.9.1 with dart editor build 44672

I have already tried pub cache repair on the cmd and it didn't help.

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: angulardart
version: 0.0.1
description: An absolute bare-bones web app.
environment:
   sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular: '1.1.0'
  browser: '>=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0'
  web_components: '>=0.10.0+2 <0.11.0'
transformers:
  angular
```

Anything would be helpful.

**Edit**
I have tried running pub get --trace and it did not work

I have also tried removing the constraints and running just any version of my dependencies. It still returns the same warning and issue:
"Pub get failed, [69] Resolving dependencies...
Connection closed before full header was received

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **"

My pubspec.yaml for this try is:

```
name: angulardart
version: 0.0.1
description: An absolute bare-bones web app.
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular: any
  browser: any
  web_components: any
transformer:
  angular
```

Comment: Can you please try `pub get --trace `.  Seems similar https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!topic/bugs/lzgSPaNCRXo

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer so what does that command do exactly? I ran it and it looks like its going a billion miles an hour through dart packages.

Comment: This produces just more verbose output for diagnosis. It seems stuck while trying to find a compatible set of dependency versions. Mabe there is no set that satisfies your constraints.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That is interesting. That's the setup that is recommended on the angular dart website. Maybe I'll try any version and see if it still throws an error.

Comment: It might be a bug in pub like the one I linked to. Usually there is no such  problem with such a short list of dependencies.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that is what I was originally thinking before I posted this but I didn't want to jump to any conclusions before exploring user error. That is the most likely thing, especially since I am using the new version of dart that came out yesterday. I will file an issue. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues seems to be an error in the latest build of dart sdk 1.9.1 and I have submitted an issue with the developers in google code.

issue link: http://dartbug.com/23004

Comment: Adding links from here to the issue and back would be great.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The link to this discussion in the issue is in the comments at google code if you are wondering.